# playing an audio automatically after a button is selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have 4 buttons in my html. i am selecting a button randomly and want to play a sound for selected button.

this is my index.js

```
buttonColours=["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
gamePattern=[];
function nextSequence(){
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
  gamePattern.push(buttonColours[r]);
  var b = gamePattern[0];
$("#"+b).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
var a = new Audio("sounds\\"+b+".mp3");
a.play();
}
nextSequence();
```

i am getting this error on the console.

> index.js:12 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first

Comment: The error means exactly what it says: auto-playing sounds on websites is frowned upon, and most browsers don't allow it. Implement a start game button and make its click handler call `nextSequence`.

Comment: @ChrisG is there anyway i can do without creating a new function to start the game?

Comment: This is why games have a "start" button over the center of the screen: it's just to get the user to click on something to start the music.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Browsers won't allow you to autoplay music without an action from the user himself. You can use a button to call your function. It could look something like this:

```
<button id="start">Start</button>
```

```
var start = document.getElementById("start");

start.onclick = function() {
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
  gamePattern.push(buttonColours[r]);
  var b = gamePattern[0];
$("#"+b).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
var a = new Audio("sounds\\"+b+".mp3");
a.play();
}
```